# How can i use custom separator characters money values?

Tags: sql-server, currency

I want to show result from my price table with specific format like this:

```
$2536360.23 ==> 2"536"360/23
```

I´ve wrote this code,
Please help me to complete:

```
Declare     @Input           Money = 2536360.23
,           @Seprator        Char(1) = '"'
,           @DecimalPointer  Char(1) = '/'
```

Comment: That is something for your presentation layer, not SQL Server. Tag the programming language, or application your using.

Comment: Cross post on [SSC](https://www.sqlservercentral.comforums/topic/separate-money-value-by-character).

Comment: This question is for education purpose. i dont use application. only for learning SQL Server. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with Larnu that this should not really be done in the database layer, but it is possible.

So if you are just interested in learning the "how":

```
Declare     @Input           Money = 2536360.23
,           @Seprator        Char(1) = '"'
,           @DecimalPointer  Char(1) = '/'

SELECT 
    REPLACE(
        REPLACE(
            REPLACE(                
                FORMAT(@Input, 'C', 'en-us'), -- this puts it in the expected starting format $2,536,360.23
                                              -- if you skip the last parameter, it would be based on whatever your local culture is set to
                                              -- e.g. I am British so for me it would say £2,536,360.23
            ',', @Seprator), 
        '.', @DecimalPointer), 
    '$', '');
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider not using the FORMAT function, ever.  At least not in SQL Server.  I was really happy to see it come out until I tested for performance.

Here's a test for this post along with a faster possibility...

```
--===== Create some test data. =============================================================
     -- This is NOT a part of the solution. We're just building test data here.
 SELECT TOP (1000000)
        SomeMoneyValue = CONVERT(MONEY,CHECKSUM(NEWID())/100.0)
   INTO #TestTable
   FROM      sys.all_columns ac1
  CROSS JOIN sys.all_columns ac2
;
GO
/*******************************************************************************************
 In the following code, the output is dumped to a variable to take disk and display times
 out of the picture.
*******************************************************************************************/
GO
PRINT'
--===== Run the BASELINE code with no formatting ==========================================';
DECLARE @BitBucket MONEY
;
    SET STATISTICS TIME,IO ON;
 SELECT @BitBucket =SomeMoneyValue
   FROM #TestTable;
    SET STATISTICS TIME,IO OFF;
GO

PRINT'
--===== Run the CONVERT code ===============================================================';
DECLARE @BitBucket VARCHAR(30)
;
    SET STATISTICS TIME,IO ON;
 SELECT @BitBucket = REPLACE(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(30),SomeMoneyValue,1),',','"'),'.','/')
   FROM #TestTable;
    SET STATISTICS TIME,IO OFF;
GO
PRINT'
--===== Run the FORMAT code, take a nap ====================================================';
DECLARE @BitBucket VARCHAR(30)
;
    SET STATISTICS TIME,IO ON;
 SELECT @BitBucket = REPLACE(REPLACE(FORMAT(SomeMoneyValue, 'C', 'en-us'),',','"'),'.','/')
   FROM #TestTable;
    SET STATISTICS TIME,IO OFF;
GO
--===== Housekeeping =======================================================================
   DROP TABLE #TestTable
;
GO
```

Here are the results:

```
(1000000 rows affected)

--===== Run the BASELINE code with no formatting ==========================================
Table '#TestTable______________________________________________________________________________
0000006218B0'. Scan count 1, logical reads 2101, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logi

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 156 ms,  elapsed time = 153 ms.

--===== Run the CONVERT code ===============================================================
Table '#TestTable______________________________________________________________________________
0000006218B0'. Scan count 1, logical reads 2101, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logi

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 1032 ms,  elapsed time = 1038 ms.

--===== Run the FORMAT code, take a nap ====================================================
Table '#TestTable______________________________________________________________________________
0000006218B0'. Scan count 1, logical reads 2101, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logi

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 32875 ms,  elapsed time = 36664 ms.
```

As far as not doing this type of thing is SQL Server goes, I do firmly believe that the Presentation Layer and the Data Layer should usually be kept separated.  There are instances, like making a file with some strange formats, where doing it all in SQL Server will cut your network traffic in half without adding much in the line of stress on your database server.